# MSSQL query for many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, many-to-many

I have a weird scenario with 4 tables with many to many relation. Below is the tables I have:

```
Employee
-------- 
EmpId (Pk)
Name

Dept
--------
DeptId (Pk)
Name

EmpDept
---------
EmpId (pk)
DeptId (pk)
```

This is a many to many table 1 employee may belong to more than 1 dept

```
Project
---------
ProjId (Pk)
EmpId (pk)
```

This is also many to many where 1 employee may be part of more than 1 project irrespective of dept.

There is no mapping between dept and project.

I need to get details of all the project an employee is part of from all depts grouped by depts. I am totally lost writing the query. All I could write is

```
select * 
from Project 
where empId in (select empid from EmpDept)
```

What I am missing is `deptID`, how can I include this?

[Example data shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xViya.jpg)

Comment: You can go to DeptId using EmpId in EmpDept Table  table by join Condition

Comment: Please post data set and wished result set

Comment: Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to include an mcve in your question - it will mean you get much higher quality answers.

Comment: you are aware that including department (via a join) will give you repeating rows where the employees will appear more than once if they are in more than one department? is this desired?

Comment: Yes. Indeed, I have attached an expected result

Comment: Is my answer showing the correct result

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Following code

```
Select P.Name,D.name,E.name from Project P 
join EmpDept Ep
on P.EmpId=Ep.EmpId 
join Dept d
on d.DeptId=p.EmpId 
group by d.name,P.Name,E.Name
```

Simply add the Columns in group and select list which you want in select list.

Comment: Looks like there's a typo in your join: `on P.EmpId=P.EmpId` should be `on Ep.EmpId=P.EmpId`, right?

Comment: Why `GROUP BY` when there are no aggregate functions involved?

Comment: You can use distinct but i use group by istead of distinct

Comment: I removed the group by and made it multi select. This worked for me
-----------------------

'select d.deptId,p.* from Department d, project p where d.empId = p.empId'